# how to init an iterator

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

i just intent to initialize an iterator over a generic linked list like that (generic typ T seems to be erased in here since the site interpret it as tag)

```
public <T> LinkedList<T> sort(LinkedList<T> list){
    Iterator<T> iter = new list.iterator();
    ...
```

but i got the error:

"list cannot be resolved"

what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To further clarify Mykola's correct answer: you're trying to create a new object of the class `list`.  So you just want to call `list.iterator()` (which, somewhere inside it, is itself doing `new Iterator` or something like it and returning that to you).

Since you're clearly using Java 5 or above, though, the better way might be instead of doing

```
public <T> LinkedList<T> sort(LinkedList<T> list){
    Iterator<T> iter = new list.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        T t = iter.next();
        ...
    }
}
```

instead doing this:

```
public <T> LinkedList<T> sort(LinkedList<T> list){
    for (T t : list){
        ...
    }
}
```

Still better, don't write that method at all and instead use

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 12):

Remove the `new` keyword:

```
Iterator<T> iter = list.iterator();
```

Answer (score 1):

The word followed by new operator must be a Class name. Here list.iterator() is already returning a Object. So at this point new is uncessary.